# Json parsing with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a json file that looks like this:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "data": {
        "employeeId": "515552",
        "firstName": "Name",
        "lastName": "LastName",
        "locationName": "Location Name",
        "businessUnitName": "Unit",
        "workPhone": "212/465-5555",
        "cellPhone": "646/261-5555",
        "faxNumber": "",
        "assistant": "",
        "email": "Name.Lastname@unit.com",
        "reportsTo": [
            {
                "employeeId": "533953",
                "firstName": "Howard",
                "lastName": "Jacobs",
                "jobTitle": "EVP Marketing & Sales Teams"
            }
        ],
        "departnemtId": "649654910",
        "departnemtName": "Action Sports Administration",
        "jobTitle": "VP Action Sports/Transform Dev"
    }
}
```

I am using an Ajax call to push the data into an array, but I can't seem to figure out the proper way to get to the `reportsTo` data.  It's the last one and I'm getting `Undefined`:

```
// Load the Employee Details on the index.page  
$.ajax({
            url: "user-details-515552.json",
            cache: true,
            dataType : 'json',

            success : function(results) {
                var employeeData = [];
                    employeeData.push({
                        assistant: results.data.assistant,
                        departmentID: results.data.departnemtId,
                        departmentName: results.data.departnemtName,
                        locationName: results.data.locationName,
                        reportsToName: results.data.reportsTo.employeeId
                    });

                $('#employee-details').tmpl(employeeData).appendTo('#results-container');

            } 

        });
```

Comment: reportsTo is an array, will there be cases of having more than one person?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reportsTo is an array ([]) containing one object ({}) so you will need to access the first element of the array ([0]) first:

```
results.data.reportsTo[0].employeeId
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case `reportsTo` is an array (see the `[` and `]`?):

```
{ // ...
  "data" : {
    // ...
    "reportsTo": [
      { "employeeId": "533953",
        // ...
      }
    ],
    // ...
}
```

...so you need to supply an array index, e.g.:

```
results.data.reportsTo[ 0 ].employeeId
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is this: here you try to get it by the property name of the object:

```
reportsToName: results.data.reportsTo.employeeId
```

Yet you pushed this earlier on in an array:

```
"reportsTo": [
            {
                "employeeId": "533953",
                "firstName": "Howard",
                "lastName": "Jacobs",
                "jobTitle": "EVP Marketing & Sales Teams"
            }
        ],
```

I'm not sure.. but I think the solution is to set

```
results.data.reportsTo.employeeId
```

to

```
results.data.reportsTo[0].employeeId
```

(not sure though..) It might be easier to just remove the `[]`..

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(json.data.reportsTo,function(k,v){
console.log(v.firstName);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pCAQp/5/

to get a single value from the array

```
console.log(json.data.reportsTo[0].firstName);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pCAQp/9/

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var reportsTo in results.data.reportsTo){
   //use reportsTo
}
```